# $\exists f \in L(V,V)$ such that $\ker(f ) = W_1$ and $\operatorname{Im} (f ) = W_2$ $\iff \dim W_1 + \dim W_2 = \dim V$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $W_1$ et $W_2$ two vector subspaces of $V$ a $K$-vector space of finite dimension. Show that it exists $f \in L(V,V)$ such that $\ker(f ) = W_1$ and $\operatorname{Im} (f ) = W_2$ $\iff$ $\dim W_1 + \dim W_2 = \dim V.$

For $\implies$, by rank theorem we have that $\dim V = \dim \ker f + \dim \operatorname{Im} f = \dim W_1 + \dim W_2$.

For the other direction, I am not sure of what I am doing : we have that $\dim W_1 + \dim W_2 = \dim V$ so $$\dim (W_1+W_2) + \dim(W_1 \cap W_2) = \dim V$$ but I don't really know how it can be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ be a basis of $V$ such that $\{e_1,\ldots,e_k\}$ is a basis of $W_1$. Let $\{f_1,\ldots,f_{n-k}\}$ be a basis of $W_2$. Now take $f\colon V\longrightarrow V$ such that $f(e_i)=0$ if $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,k\}$ and that $f(e_i)=f_{i-k}$ otherwise. Then $\ker f=W_1$ and $\operatorname{Im}f=W_2$.